# Storing images on linux

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I'm building website with billions of images. I'm little confused to store images in single directory. how many images can be stored in single directory. or it slow down the server ?

Comment: For  billions of images I would consider binary blobs inside a database. If you want to use files, consider at least a schema such as `/data/dir123/subdir345/image67890.jpeg` like paths. Having a single directory with a billion entries does not seem reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered object storage such as AWS S3? http://aws.amazon.com/s3/

As for performance, I think it depends on the file system you intend to use. Some file systems index directory content in a linear manner, others use more efficient algorithms. It also depends whether any of your system services will need to scan the directory regularly.

I found this: http://events.linuxfoundation.org/slides/2010/linuxcon2010_wheeler.pdf

In this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/43133/filesystem-large-number-of-files-in-a-single-directory